# Raphael how to access element in Another drawing area or canvas

Tags: raphael

I have two drawing areas like `paper = raphael(...)` and `paper1= raphael(...)`. How to access elements of canvas in another...I have a path in `paper1` and i want to access its attributes from `paper`. Any suggestions?

Comment: use the proximate shared scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an element that contains both papers and access them from there...there will be no magic between the 2 different papers... or add each paper in the other, so you can do this:

```
var myCurrentPaper = myElementInPaperOne.paper;
var myOtherPaper = myCurrentPaper.paperTwoReference;
```

Comment: I thought it wont work. but i am able to access elements...from paper i can call paper1.element.....it works..